# Description of the OpenGL library and what all functions are doing

Tags: c, function, opengl

Does anyone know a good book or website, where you can get a good description of all the functions in opengl. How they work. I know those sites where you get a short explanation and what the function expects. I mean a more accurate and exact description. Also how openGL works in general and how it works behind the scenes. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

How about the [OpenGL reference pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/)?

There's also the [OpenGL Programming Guide](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/)

Comment: I'm sure this is just me being stupid, but why are basic commands like glColor* and glVertex* missing from the reference pages you've linked to?

Answer (score 2):

We had the question about how OpenGL works behind the scenes a few days ago already. See my answer here:
[How does OpenGL work at the lowest level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399676/how-does-opengl-work-at-the-lowest-level/6401607#6401607)

Comment: +1 the linked answer is a nice summary.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the details of every function in the API, the links already mentioned are your best bet.

If you need an extremely thorough look into how OpenGL works, though, you can't beat the official specifications for completeness:

- [The OpenGL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec41.core.20100725.pdf) for the CPU side of things
- [the GLSL Language specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.00.8.clean.pdf) for the GPU (shaders) side