# If context is specific platform, how does OpenGL read it?

Tags: opengl

I read some article said OpenGL Context is create by GUI server, but how does OpenGL read it? Is an OpenGL implementation cross-platform?

Comment: OpenGL is not a library, it is a specification ([OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) ). The OpenGL API is implemented by the graphics driver.

Comment: And why context is generate by GUI server? and how does OpenGL implementation read context?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: @AlanJian: The implementation *is the context*. Or rather, the context represents the implementation.

Comment: The context section in OpenGL's wikipedia

Comment: Does the wgl, glx... request a OpenGL implementation for its context format from driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does OpenGL work at the lowest level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399676/how-does-opengl-work-at-the-lowest-level)

Comment: So, could you explain the relation ship of operating system, OpenGL and something like wgl? and why context is specific platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation of OpenGL is the actual code that implements the OpenGL specification. An OpenGL context is a particular interface to an OpenGL implementation, along with whatever state data and objects are needed for that interface.

OpenGL does not "read" the context; OpenGL *is the context*. Without a context, there is no interface to a valid OpenGL implementation, and without a valid OpenGL implementation, there is no OpenGL.

Implementations are specific to the hardware that they are written for.

Comment: So does the GUI server request an OpenGL implementation specific its context from driver?

Comment: @AlanJian: I don't know what your question means. It's not clear what you're trying to understand.

Comment: Does the wgl, glx... request a OpenGL implementation for its context format from driver?

Comment: @AlanJian: I don't know what a "context format" is, but the OS acts as the intermediary between the user and the driver in terms of OpenGL context creation. That is, the user asks the OS to create a context, and the OS selects a driver to ask to create a context.