# Where are the shaders compiled into machine code in Nouveau driver?

Tags: opengl, mesa

I am learning about how the OpenGL pipeline works in consideration of the OpenGL API and the driver. According to this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399676/how-does-opengl-work-at-the-lowest-level/6401607#6401607), one of the duties of the GPU driver is to

> compile shaders in the machine code of the GPU

To have a better understanding, I started to examine the code of Nouveau driver, as it is opensource: [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/nouveau). As far as I can understand, there should be a specific part in this repo, where the shaders are compiled into machine code. So the driver, indirectly implements the`glCompileShader()` method after it has been translated to the driver specific functions by the OpenGL client library (in that case: by Mesa).

I would like to know, which part of the Nouveau driver is responsible for the above method.

Comment: one part seems to be [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/nouveau/mesa/-/tree/nvk/main/src/nouveau/codegen) which seems to have the parts that are different for different GPU architectures. To get a better look I'd suggest downloading the code, opening it with your favourite IDE, and then using the cross-reference features in your IDE to see where this stuff is called from